# Trying to use standard JTree implementation, but the output is really messed up

Tags: java, swing, display, jtree

I'm trying to use JTree. Here is my example test class:

```
package inspector;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;


/**
 *
 * @author Alex
 */
public class TreeTest {

    private static ValueMap prepareTree() {
        ValueMap obj = new ValueMap();
        obj.set("x", new Value(1));
        obj.set("y", new Value(1));

        ValueArray users = new ValueArray();
        obj.set("users", users);

        ValueMap user = new ValueMap();
        user.set("login", new Value("Alex654"));
        user.set("password", new Value("123456"));

        ValueMap info = new ValueMap();
        info.set("city", new Value("Moscow"));
        info.set("job", new Value("Developer"));
        info.set("firstName", new Value("Alex"));
        info.set("lastName", new Value("Popov"));
        user.set("bio", info);

        users.push(user);

        ValueMap user2 = new ValueMap();
        user2.set("login", new Value("admin"));
        user2.set("password", new Value("test"));
        user2.set("bio", new Value(null));

        users.push(user2);

        return obj;
    }

    static class Value {

        Value() {
            value = null;
        }

        Value(Object val) {
            this.value = val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (value instanceof Integer || value instanceof Double) {
                return value + "";
            } else {
                return "\"" + value.toString() + "\"";
            }
        }

        Object value;
    }

    static class ValueArray extends Value {

        ValueArray() {
            items = new ArrayList<Value>();
        }

        ValueArray(Value val) {
            items = new ArrayList<Value>();
            items.add(val);
        }

        void push(Value val) {
            items.add(val);
        }

        ArrayList<Value> items;
    }

    static class ValueMap extends Value {

        ValueMap() {
            items = new HashMap<String, Value>();
        }

        Value get(String key) {
            return items.get(key);
        }

        void put(String key, Value val) {
            items.put(key, val);
        }

        void set(String key, Value val) {
            items.put(key, val);
        }

        HashMap<String, Value> items;
    }

    public static class ValueWrapper {

        ValueWrapper(String label, Value val) {
            this.label = label;
            this.val = val;
        }

        String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        Value getValue() {
            return val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String result = label;
            if (val instanceof ValueArray) {
                result += ": Array";
            }
            else if (val instanceof ValueMap) {
                result += ": { Object }";
            }
            else result += ": " + val.toString();

            return result;
        }

        private String label;
        private Value val;
    }

    public static void processChildren(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        Value val = ((ValueWrapper)node.getUserObject()).getValue();
        if (val instanceof ValueArray) {
            ArrayList<Value> items = ((ValueArray)val).items;
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new ValueWrapper(i + "", items.get(i)));
                node.add(newNode);
                processChildren(newNode);
            }
        } else if (val instanceof ValueMap) {
            HashMap<String, Value> props = ((ValueMap)val).items;
            Set<String> keys = props.keySet();
            for (String key: keys) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new ValueWrapper(key, props.get(key)));
                node.add(newNode);
                if (!key.equals("__proto__")) {
                    processChildren(newNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        final ValueMap root = prepareTree();
        if (root == null) return;

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Object Inspector");
        JPanel cp = new JPanel();
        cp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(9, 10, 9, 10));
        frame.setContentPane(cp);
        cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cp, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new ValueWrapper("obj", root));
        processChildren(rootNode);

        DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode, true);
        final JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);

        final JPanel contentpane = new JPanel();
        contentpane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentpane.setOpaque(true);
        contentpane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentpane.add(tree);

        //contentpane.setBounds(0, 0, 490, 380);
        final int width = 490, height = 418;
        cp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        final JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(contentpane);
        scrollpane.setOpaque(false);
        scrollpane.getInsets();

        cp.add(scrollpane);
        scrollpane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scrollpane.setOpaque(true);
        //setSize(518, 420);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I expect to get a nice looking tree, like in NetBeans IDE that I use everyday.

But however I get this:

[tree display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBi0p.png)

What the heck is wrong with it? Also should note that when my labels were longer (without the "wrapper" inner class) the output labels in leaves was 2-3 times wider, but the labels were also extremely cut down in width.

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunalely, the result after suggested solution is not ideal. See the screenshot below:

[fixed display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJOGM.png)

1. The symbols are cut by 1-2 pixels from the bottom (look at the square brackets). Maybe it is a windows bug (I use Windows 7 with 150% zoom), but is there a way to fix that? To increase the font size of the labels or the vertical gap between them (so called "line height")?
2. I don't like that leaves have "+" on them until I click them. I solved it adding `else { node.setAllowsChildren(false); }` to the end of my `processChildren()` method. But now I would like to have a single custom icon for all of my nodes, whether they have children or not.

Comment: And I know that I can write a custom tree cell renderer, but this really should work fine out of the box. In NetBeans debugger it does work correctly, anyway.

Comment: At a minimum you should edit your question and describe the external libraries and classes you are using.  But even better would be to post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem using only classes in the JDK.  Your issue is with `JTree` which should be independent of those libraries.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [How to Use Trees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) section.

Comment: Well, I have to do some research but  `BoxLayout` seemed to be screwing up your display, Try the following: `contentpane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`  It seemed to display the tree just fine.  The last child throws an NPE though when you try to expand it.

Comment: Okay, now I have another problem with my tree. After I lazily load the children of any node, I need to increase the height of all my ancestor containers (in order to adjust the parent JScrollPane). I made a method that walks over all the children of JScrollPane and finds sum of their heights. That works well when I add a new tree, but does not work after new nodes are inserted into it. It works if I expand the next-to-last root's child, but not when I expand the last one...

Answer (score -1):

Seems that all the methods I needed were available either in `JTree` itself or in `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` class. Here is the final working code:

```
    private static JPanel createObjectTree(JSObject obj) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new JSValueWrapper("obj", obj));
        loadNodeDirectChildren(rootNode, false);

        DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode, true);
        final JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);
        TreeExpandListener expansionListener = new TreeExpandListener();
        tree.addTreeWillExpandListener(expansionListener);

        DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
        renderer.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        renderer.setLeafIcon(null);
        renderer.setIcon(null);
        renderer.setClosedIcon(null);
        renderer.setOpenIcon(null);
        renderer.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 20));
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        tree.setRowHeight(23);

        final JPanel contentpane = new JPanel();
        contentpane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentpane.setOpaque(true);
        contentpane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentpane.add(tree);

        return contentpane;
    }

    private static void processNodeChildren(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean show_prototypes) {
        JSValue val = ((JSValueWrapper)node.getUserObject()).getValue();
        if (val instanceof JSArray) {
            Vector<JSValue> items = ((JSArray)val).getItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new JSValueWrapper("[" + i + "]", items.get(i)));
                node.add(newNode);
                processNodeChildren(newNode, show_prototypes);
            }
        } else if (!(val instanceof Function) && !val.getType().matches("Boolean|Integer|Float|Number|String|null|undefined") && val instanceof JSObject) {
            HashMap<String, JSValue> props = ((JSObject)val).getProperties();
            Set<String> keys = props.keySet();
            for (String key: keys) {
                if (!show_prototypes && key.equals("__proto__")) continue;
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new JSValueWrapper(key, props.get(key)));
                node.add(newNode);
                if (!key.equals("__proto__")) {
                    processNodeChildren(newNode, show_prototypes);
                } else {
                    newNode.setAllowsChildren(false);
                }
            }
        } else {
            node.setAllowsChildren(false);
        }
    }

    private static void loadNodeDirectChildren(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean show_prototypes) {
        JSValue val = ((JSValueWrapper)node.getUserObject()).getValue();
        if (val instanceof JSArray) {
            Vector<JSValue> items = ((JSArray)val).getItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new JSValueWrapper("[" + i + "]", items.get(i)));
                node.add(newNode);
            }
        } else if (!(val instanceof Function) && !val.getType().matches("Boolean|Integer|Float|Number|String|null|undefined") && val instanceof JSObject) {
            HashMap<String, JSValue> props = ((JSObject)val).getProperties();
            Set<String> keys = props.keySet();
            for (String key: keys) {
                if (!show_prototypes && key.equals("__proto__")) continue;
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new JSValueWrapper(key, props.get(key)));
                node.add(newNode);
                if (props.get(key) instanceof Function || props.get(key).getType().matches("Boolean|Integer|Float|Number|String|null|undefined")) {
                    newNode.setAllowsChildren(false);
                }
                if (key.equals("__proto__")) {
                    newNode.setAllowsChildren(false);
                }
            }
        } else {
            node.setAllowsChildren(false);
        }
    }

    static class TreeExpandListener implements TreeWillExpandListener {

        @Override
        public void treeWillExpand(final TreeExpansionEvent e) throws ExpandVetoException {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
            if (node.getChildCount() == 0) {
                loadNodeDirectChildren(node, false);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((JTree)e.getSource()).invalidate();
                        ((JTree)e.getSource()).getParent().validate();
                        recalculateContentHeight();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent e) {}

        public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent e) {}

        public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent e) {}
    }
```

Note that if the tree contains "loops", e.g. in HTML document each child has a link to its parent, and every two adjacent siblings link to each other, then using simple approach of initializing all the node's children will lead to stackoverflow error and the program will crash.

The solution is to use lazy loading of children, and load only one level at a time, until the user clicks one of the existing "non-leaf" nodes.

Comment: I must admit that I still don't understand why only this combination of method calls allows to re-calculate the new scrolling amount in parent `JScrollPane` (invalidate JTree, validate its parent, and then calculate grandparent's height and set it via `setPreferredSize()`. If I remove any of these calls it breaks.